# How to hide or show divs based on checkbox change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the values based on Checkbox check and uncheck

I have got two checkboxes MNC and Worth (Only the Top Ones),  i am trying to show or hide the values based on it (pesent under class pack-panel div)

This is my code

```
$(document).on('change', '.filtermnc', function() {
 $(".pack-panel").each(function () {
    var visible = $(this).find('.mnccheckbox').prop('checked')
   $(this).toggle(visible);
  });
  });


$(document).on('change', '.filterworth', function() {
 $(".pack-panel").each(function () {
    var visible = $(this).find('.worthcheckbox').prop('checked')
   $(this).toggle(visible);
  });
  });
```

When i tried with this code , it is not working and also it is checking all the correspondng checkboxes

Could you please let me know how to achieve this .
http://jsfiddle.net/F8Vk2/121/

Comment: why downvote , i have tried but its not working as expected .

Comment: you want to hide the whole `pack-panel` if the corresponding checkbox is checked or something else?

Comment: @depperm  , based on the upper checkbox selection i need to hide or show the pack-panel div's

Comment: Shouldn't the hide/show  be conditional on the top checkbox states also? Not clear what expected behavior is

Comment: @charlietfl , please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F8Vk2/125/ , this is working fine but only for Worth Checkbox chnage event only and not for MNC

Comment: Broken code is not a substitute for a proper explantion of expected behavior. That demo makes no sense to me

Comment: okay , if you dont mind could you please see this http://jsfiddle.net/F8Vk2/129/

Answer (score 0):

Change your js to

```
   $(document).on('change', '.filtermnc', function() {
    var visible = $(this).prop('checked')
    if(visible)
       $('.mnccheckbox').closest("li").show();
    else
       $('.mnccheckbox').closest("li").hide();
  });


$(document).on('change', '.filterworth', function() {
var visible = $(this).prop('checked')
    if(visible)
       $('.worthcheckbox').closest("li").show();
    else
       $('.worthcheckbox').closest("li").hide();

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8Vk2/123/

Comment: is this jquery in your answer any different then the OP?

Comment: Change what? looks the same. Explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

I made for one, but it's just a mater of changing the other one likewise:

```
$(document).on('change', '.filterworth, .filtermnc', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    isChecked = $this.is(':checked'),
    $packPanel = $('.pack-panel');

  isChecked ? $packPanel.show() : $packPanel.hide()

 });
```

You could use `this` to get the target of the event and verify if it's checked by `.is(':checked')`. Also, you don't need to iterate over `$('.pack-panel')` in order to apply your changes. `.toggle()` will change the visibility by it's previous one, so I think you should hard code to hide or show the panels.

Comment: this is working only for Worth checkbox , not for MNC checkbox

Comment: Edited it to make it work for both checkboxes, @UnKnown.

Comment: i ran your code ths is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F8Vk2/126/  but i am getting VM79:45 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Sorry for that. There was a `'` extra in the selector parameter.

Comment: corrected that , but still its not working as expectd http://jsfiddle.net/F8Vk2/128/

Comment: I mean i selected both the checkboxes , it should display only Infosys in this condition , but its displaying both of them

Answer (score -1):

You could try ->

```
$(document).on('change', '.filtermnc', function() {
   $('.mnccheckbox').
     closest("li").
     toggle($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

This is basically finding all with .mccheckbox class, and then toggling based on the property of the checkbox you assigned the event too.

Comment: Interesting, vote down. but yet it works.  I've explained what I've done. etc.  Some people on here need there head testing..